# create new MySQL database and user using OS root credentials

Tags: mysql

I have root permissions on a server (running Redhat):

```
[root@myserver /]#
```

... but not on the MySQL instance that's running on the server:

```
[root@myserver /]# mysql -u root   
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

I'd like to create a new database on the MySQL instance (version 5.6.26), and an account with `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ...` on the new database.

Is this possible (e.g. using `mysqladmin`) using only the OS root account?

Comment: I am curious, what is your use case here? _Should_ you have root access on this MySQL server? Have you tried logging in with the `-p` flag, and MySQL prompting you for a password? If you think that you should have root, or forgot your password, [here is a great guild](http://www.rackspace.com/knowledge_center/article/mysql-resetting-a-lost-mysql-root-password) to help you reset your MySQL Password. If this is a non-production server, it seem to me like starting a whole new instance just for a new database seems like a lot of overhead.

Comment: Thanks @MattClark. I really like the `mysqld_safe` approach to bypass the credentials. The use case is that I have a Hadoop ETL job that persists counts/status in MySQL, and the MySQL box I happen to have access to is a shared development instance (other dev's execute ad-hoc DDL so I can't use a proper migration tool such as Flyway). Since the Hadoop cluster already has MySQL running (for the Hive metastore, Oozie scheduler, etc...), and I'm responsible for the cluster, this is a natural home for the ETL state.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you will need to install another, separate instance of MySQL, configure it to run on a different port, specify that port in your login screen, and then do as you like.

You can do this by simply installing MySQL to another disk location, and then editing the ini file.  On Windows and Mac installations, this is called my.ini

Alternatively, I think your only choice is to get permissions granted to you on the currently installed MySQL instance.  The root password to the OS and the root password to the MySQL server instance are entirely distinct (as I'm sure you know).